# Image marker Google maps api Html

Tags: html, maps, google-maps-markers

I was just playing around trying to do something with Google maps api in html however I ran into an issue. I am currently trying to place markers at specific positions, specifically customized markers that show as images not the regular markers however I can not figure out the code to do so. Currently this is an example of what I have attempted doing:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Advanced map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script>
function init() {
blatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.275890,-73.874195);
myOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: blatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.Map     };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("italy"),   myOptions);


blatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.155889,106.640180);
myOptions1 = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: blatlng1,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.Map     };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("home"), myOptions1);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: blatlng,
icon: "jess1.jpg"
});
marker.setMap(map);
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="init();">
<div id="italy" style="width:500px; height:300px"></div>
home
<div id="home" style="width:500px; height:300px"></div>
</body> </html>
```

This is the specific section where I am trying to place the custom marker however this also only calls the initial coordinates if it did work I just want to be able to place an image marker anywhere on either map:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: blatlng,
icon: "jess1.jpg"
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier It is coming up with: [Warning] Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys (util.js, line 228)
[Warning] Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required (util.js, line 228)

Comment: I would also like to point out that I cannot use the source code: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap",  to call the map because where I will be hosting this won't be https but http

Comment: Might be an idea to get an API key. To get more answers, you might also want to add your code to a plunkr

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier I think it may be an issue with having two maps because I have it successfully working with a single map. Neither of those errors actually matter, the one with sensor not required is simply due to the sensor technique being outdated and it is not needed for the api, however with or without does not make a difference. The other as you had mentioned is about an API key however for what I am doing it is not needed either, it is simply remarking that I do not have one and I may need one depending on what I am doing. I am assuming it is confused with two maps.